Manga with a female main character who can swap places with her older self
This manga (manhwa/manhua?) story is about a female main character who has the ability to switch her place with her 20 years older self, that has been happening after she and her aunt and cousins got attacked by people after she got back from the church. The third time is in the conference with the king.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.   Where and when did you read this?  Was it in black-and-white or colour?  Do you recall any distinguishing features of the main character?  (e.g. hair colour, eye colour, etc.)

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Could this be Golden Light Gratia, The Child Loved By God?

Gratia, a girl considered useless and despised by her family, has a revealing dream where a mysterious man predicts a great future for her. She soon discovers that she is the lost daughter of the influential Luciffero family. In a surprising event, after being attacked, a golden light erupts from Gratia, forcing everyone around her to close their eyes. When the light dissipates, young Gratia disappears and in her place an adult version of herself appears, with distinct features of Luciffero. With an imposing stature and undeniable beauty, she comes across Nea, her mother, and realizes that the transformation expected for the future happened that day. This was the moment when ten-year-old Gratia and twenty-year-old Gratia switched bodies for the first time


